# Do Liouville theory have a gravity dual?

Tags: gravity, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft, holographic-principle, duality

1. Does [Liouville theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Liouville+theory) have a gravity dual? I think the answer is not. But what's wrong with Liouville theory?
2. What features of [Liouville theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_field_theory) are universal for other CFTs?

Comment: I don't know about liouville theory, but on the page you are linking it says there is "an argument that 3d quantum gravity with negative cosmological constant has as boundary field theory 2d Liouville theory". So..  the answer to your first question would be "yes"?

Comment: @Noiralef Note that it is not OP who is linking, but Qmechanic who added the links.

Comment: To Nahc: *Why* do you think the answer is no for your first question, and why is that reason not sufficient for you? Please add further context to your question so that answerers will know where you are coming from - right now it is very difficult to tell what sort of explanation this question is asking for.